# Laravel 5.8 cron job for php artisan schedul:run

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.8

I added cron job this in my host:

`* * * * *  cd /home/mydomain/public_html/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

And kernel file:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   file_put_contents(base_path('public/temp/test.txt'),'test_string');
}
```

But it doesn't create the file and when I added this in my cron job, It creates folders every minute.

`* * * * *  cd /home/mydomain/public_html/ && mkdir test_folder >> /dev/null 2>&1`

And when I run this command in terminal `php artisan schdule:run` it creates the `test.txt` file.

Comment: when do you want to create the file?

Comment: Does the folder `public/temp` exist?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes of course

Comment: Your cronjob works? just your command doesn't work?

Comment: can you test another command . for example Log::info('this is test') . if it works so your should change base_path to absolute path

Comment: @TsaiKoga this is test schedule command. My schedule is other thing. I change to this `file_put_contents(base_path('public/temp/tset.txt'),'test_string');` to be sure that schdule is run

Comment: @TsaiKoga I edit my post

Comment: @aliFalahati  I edit my post

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't call it by `$schedule`,

check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#defining-schedules

And your code need to be like this:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->call(function () {
       if (!file_exists(public_path('temp'))) {
          mkdir(public_path('temp') , 0777);
       }
       file_put_contents(base_path('public/temp/tset.txt'),'test_string');
   })->dailyAt('2:10');  
}
```

If you use `php artisan schedule:run` it will automatically fire the events: ["schedule:run source code"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L65)

And you don't have any events, it will display `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`.

However, that file be created is because you overwrite the schedule function, it supports to be empty originally.  [schedule](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php#L169)

Comment: It dose not create file.

Comment: @paranoid Try this in your cron: `* * * * * /your_php_path/bin/php /home/mydomain/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @paranoid check the crontab status `ps aux | grep crond`, is that running?

Comment: result : 237  0.0  0.0   6492   604 ?        SN+  03:19   0:00 grep --color crond

Comment: @paranoid It seems your cron service is not running. try to run `/etc/init.d/crond start` or `service crond start`

Comment: my SHH in on host and can not run `service crond start`. I think that this service is start because I run this `* * * * *  cd /home/mydomain/public_html/ && mkdir test_folder >> /dev/null 2>&1` it create test_folder

Comment: @paranoid try this:`* * * * * /your_php_path/bin/php /home/mydomain/public_html/artisan schedule:run >>  /your_path/output.txt ` and check the **output.txt**, see the message.

Comment: It not create output.txt file

Comment: @paranoid I have try in my env, whatever your command is wrong, it will still create the output.txt, unless the cron service is not running, or your path is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your function with `$schedule`

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    file_put_contents(base_path('public/temp/tset.txt'),'test_string');
})->everyFiveMinutes();
```

Or Make [`command` class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands) and run through it

Read [Defining Schedules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#defining-schedules)

Comment: I added this  but dose not create file

Comment: try `Storage::append('tset.txt', 'Appended Text');` and check first